# How to read only half of a file?

Tags: c++

I open the file like this if I want to read the whole file

```
ifstream file;
file.open ("test.txt", ios :: binary);
```

But I want to get only half of the contents of the file, not all of them.

I will get half of it from the test file, not all of it.

How is it done?

Comment: Why does your title say "whole file" if you only want half? and what is half? Number of lines, or characters, or something else? Please clarify the question.

Comment: Either determine the size beforehand and read only half of it or read all of it and just discard the 2nd half.

Comment: How do I measure it?

Comment: If you have c++17 this: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size)

Comment: Concerning _determine the size beforehand_: [std::filesystem::file_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size). This is _a bit_ unreliable because once you determined the size you still have no guarantee that another process modifies the file until you read it (theoretically)...

Comment: You could read the whole file in a loop e.g. `std::string buffer; for (char c; file.get(c);) buffer.push_back(c);`. Afterwards, you can retrieve the overall size by `buffer.size()`.

Answer (score 2):

A pre C++17 version could be to seek to the end of the file to determine the size and then to reset the input position to the beginning again.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::copy
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>  // std::istreambuf_iterator

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
    if(file) {
        // Set input position indicator to the end of the file:
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);

        // Get the input position indicator at the end:
        auto size = file.tellg();

        // Set input position indicator back to the beginning of the file:
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        // create a container for the data, half the size of the file size:
        std::vector<char> data(size / 2);

        // read half the file
        std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), data.size(), data.begin());
    }
}
```

With C++17, [`std::filesystem::file_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size) makes it a lot easier:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    auto size = std::filesystem::file_size("test.txt");

    std::ifstream file("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
    if(file) {
        // create a container for the data, half the size of the file size:
        std::vector<char> data(size / 2);

        // read half the file
        std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), data.size(), data.begin());
    }
}
```